# 1-wire humidity sensor with ID

Tags: sensor, temperature, 1-wire, humidity

I've created a temperature monitoring system using multiple DS18B20 temperature sensors and now I want to add some humidity sensors to it. The problem is that I cant find any 1-wire humidity or temperature/humidity sensors that use ID logic similar to DS18B20 (when you can get all IDs in the beginning and after that ask each by it's own ID). Is there really no such humidity sensors or I'm just missing something?

Comment: There may not be, and shopping questions are off-topic here anyway. But it's straightforward to convert any sensor to 1-wire protocol using a small microcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1923.pdf

iButtons are using the 1wire protocol for communication. They are intended to be used standalone, to eg. control environmental conditions during shipping of sensitive goods, but it is possible to connect them permanently to a 1wire bus.

The particular device seems to be a bit pricey (for the job).